# Why is there no getOnClickListener in the Button class? (Android)

Tags: android, api, button

Why is there no getOnClickListener in the Button class? I think this is really strange considering there is a getOnFocusChangeListener function. Why make it for the FocusChangeListener and not for the ClickListener?

---

Added comment:

For those below that are wondering why I need this: We are developing a large application with a lot of viewgroups on the screen. I want to add some code to a button on the screen but not replace the complete OnClickListener. I want to implement a new OnClickListener that will run some code and call the old OnClickListener. But for that I need to retrieve the old one.

Comment: May I ask why do you need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a question to Google :D

Why do you need to get a onClickListener back? If you are so desperate, store it in a tag (Views.setTag(...));

Comment: He could also just save the listener in a variable in his activity before calling setOnClickListener(). In this case he can access it easily...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why there is not, but you can do what you want to do by extending the button class:

```
public class Button extends android.widget.Button implements OnClickListener {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        /* Your code here...*/

        super().onClick(v);
    }
}
```